# NoMoreData exception when using couchdbkit with gunicorn and eventlet

Tags: python, gunicorn, eventlet, couchdbkit

Hope someone might be able to shed some light on this issue I'm having.

I am using couchdbkit in a pyramid webapp. My server is gunicorn with eventlet workers.

I am using the eventlet manager for couchdbkit.

When my app is running, I get quite frequently NoMoreData exceptions from couchdbkit (actually http parser inside restkit).
My hunch is that this has something to do with one connection waiting for eventlet is getting the data of a different waiting connection but I am not sure.

Did anyone encounter this problem? Do you have an idea?

Thanks,
Reshef